# Is there any way to add the css class to tinymce inside wysiwyg editor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have several classes defined inside `style.css`, I want `tinymce` to recognize these classes. Below is the popup to configure hyperlinks. It also provide a way to use `css` styles defined already.

[image]

I am looking for a way to add the `css` class to `tinymce` inside `wysiwyg` editor in Drupal 7.

Comment: Which module you are using? tinymce or wysiwyg?

Comment: @JimmyKo: module is `wysiwyg` and library is `tinymce`

Comment: What is the version of tinymce?

Comment: @JimmyKo: Version 3.5.11

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using [wysiwyg](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module with [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com) library. You should implement the alter function provided by wysiwyg module to add the editor settings.

For tinymce 4.x:

```
function MYMODULE_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'tinymce') {
    $settings['link_class_list'] = array(
      "Class Example" => "class-example",
    );
  }
}
```

For tinymce 3.x:

```
function MYMODULE_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter(&$settings, $context) {
  if ($context['profile']->editor == 'tinymce') {
    $settings['theme_advanced_styles'] = array(
      "Class Example" => "class-example",
    );
  }
}
```

## References

- [documentation of tinymce 4.x](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/#link_class_list)
- [documentation of tinymce 3.x](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:theme_advanced_styles)
- [API of wysiwyg](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!wysiwyg!wysiwyg.api.php/function/hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter/7)